# Using beautifulsoup to click through pages and then search for appropriate links to open and scrape

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've had a good look around and I am wondering if it is possible. I am trying to scrape some sports statistics from https://www.scoreboard.com/en/soccer/england/premier-league/

I am using these for the scraper and csv export:

```
import requests
import re
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

When the scraper gets there I'd like it to click on games that have a final score (so I might have to automate the scraper to go on Friday, Saturday, Sunday and Monday at midnight). From there, I'd like the scraper to click "statistics" and this will open up the URL that is needed to be scraped in a new window.

[image]

From there it would be ideal to go through all the matches of that week and scrape the stats.

Is this even possible with Beautifulsoup?

I can scrape each page by manually adding in the links and then for the output data I have to make a new .csv file for each. I don't mind that, it's pretty quick. I have all that ready to go - but if I can automate it, then definitely, I'd love to learn how.

Comment: BS parses the data but how are you actually downloading the page? Requests or Selenium?

Comment: Sorry, I did miss that. Requests. I'll edit and add that.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things that makes this site hard to scrape using beautifulsoup alone :

- the data is not in plain text in the html. It's located in the `div` with id `tournament-page-data-results` like this :

  ```
  SA÷1¬~ZA÷ENGLAND: Premier League¬ZEE÷dYlOSQOD¬ZB÷198¬ZY÷England¬ZC÷zTRyeuJg¬ZD÷t¬ZE÷AJuiuwWt¬ZF÷0¬ZO÷0¬ZG÷1¬ZH÷198_dYlOSQOD¬ZJ÷2¬ZL÷/en/soccer/england/premier-league/¬ZX÷00England     007ngland0000000000001000Premier Leag014League000¬ZCC÷0¬ZAF÷England¬~AA÷6J0L2p0r¬AD÷1601835300¬ADE÷1601835300¬AB÷3¬CR÷3¬AC÷3¬CX÷Aston Villa¬ER÷Round 4¬RW÷0¬AX÷1¬AO÷1601842143¬BX÷-1¬HMC÷1¬WQ÷¬WN÷LIV¬AF÷Liverpool¬JB÷Yi2C1SGu¬WV÷liverpool¬AH÷2¬BB÷1¬BD÷1¬WM÷AST¬AE÷Aston Villa¬JA÷f3v9dzKU¬WU÷aston-villa¬AS÷1¬AZ÷1¬AG÷7¬BA÷4¬BC÷3¬AW÷1¬~AA÷l2dtbMED¬AD÷1601825400¬ADE÷1601825400¬AB÷3¬CR÷3¬AC÷3¬CX÷Manchester Utd¬ER÷Round 4¬RW÷0¬AX÷1¬AO÷1601832194¬BX÷-1¬HMC÷1¬WQ÷¬WN÷TOT¬AF÷Tottenham¬JB÷IHkhE50o¬WV÷tottenham¬AS÷2¬AZ÷2¬AH÷6¬BB÷4¬BD÷2¬WM÷MNU¬AE÷Manchester Utd¬JA÷U1dAkMNp¬WU÷manchester-united¬AJ÷1¬AG÷1¬BA÷1¬BC÷0¬AW÷1¬~AA÷0xOh7QiR¬AD÷1601816400¬ADE÷1601816400¬AB÷3¬CR÷3¬AC÷3¬CX÷Arsenal¬ER÷Round 4¬RW÷0¬AX÷1¬AO÷1601823089¬BX÷-1¬HMC÷1¬WQ÷¬WM÷ARS¬AE÷Arsenal¬JA÷MyR1bdkI¬WU÷arsenal¬AS÷1¬AZ÷1¬AG÷2¬BA÷0¬BC÷2¬WN÷SHU¬AF÷Sheffield Utd¬JB÷GCu5cG4O¬WV÷sheffield-utd¬AH÷1¬BB÷0¬BD÷1¬AW÷1¬~AA÷rFhWKqMQ¬AD÷1601816400¬ADE÷1601816400¬AB÷3¬CR÷3¬AC÷3¬C
  ```

It's a custom format that uses `~` as row separator, `¬` as cell delimiter and `÷` to delimite key/value. The logic can be deducted by looking at the js (the file starting with `core_*.js`. In order to parse it in [python](/questions/tagged/python) we need to reproduce the logic and add all matches for the tags (for example `ZA` is `SHAREDINDEXES_TOURNAMENT_NAME` etc..)

- the second thing is that to get to the stats page, you need a token that is hardcoded in JS in the same file `core_*.js`.

Using regex to extract token from JS is a sign that you may be better using selenium in this  case

The following code extract the match data, parse the custom format, get the js file, extract the token from it, generate the stats url and get the stats html :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re

DELIMITER_ROW = "~"
DELIMITER_CELL = "¬"
DELIMITER_VALUE = "÷"

indexes = {
    "COMMONINDEXES_AWAY_FIRST_OUTS": 'ER',
    "COMMONINDEXES_FT_WINNER": 'AZ',
    "COMMONINDEXES_ROW": 'RW',
    "FSCORE_DRAWINDEXES_ROUND_ADVANCING_PARTICIPANT": 'AE',
    "FULLFEEDINDEXES_AWAY_3CHAR_NAME": 'WN',
    "FULLFEEDINDEXES_AWAY_EVENT_PARTICIPANT_ID": 'JB',
    "FULLFEEDINDEXES_AWAY_PARTICIPANT_NAME": 'AF',
    "FULLFEEDINDEXES_AWAY_PARTICIPANT_NAME_URL": 'WV',
    "FULLFEEDINDEXES_EVENT_START_UTIME": 'ADE',
    "FULLFEEDINDEXES_HAS_MATCH_COMMENTS": 'HMC',
    "FULLFEEDINDEXES_HOME_3CHAR_NAME": 'WM',
    "FULLFEEDINDEXES_HOME_EVENT_PARTICIPANT_ID": 'JA',
    "FULLFEEDINDEXES_HOME_PARTICIPANT_NAME_URL": 'WU',
    "FULLFEEDINDEXES_SORT_PARTICIPANT": 'CX',
    "FULLFEEDINDEXES_WINNER": 'AS',
    "SHAREDINDEXES_AWAY_CURRENT_RESULT": 'AH',
    "SHAREDINDEXES_AWAY_RESULT_PERIOD_1": 'BB',
    "SHAREDINDEXES_AWAY_RESULT_PERIOD_2": 'BD',
    "SHAREDINDEXES_CRICKET_RECENT_OVERS": 'WQ',
    "SHAREDINDEXES_EVENT_ID": 'AA',
    "SHAREDINDEXES_EVENT_STAGE_ID": 'AC',
    "SHAREDINDEXES_EVENT_STAGE_TYPE_FROM_EVENT_STAGE_ID": 'CR',
    "SHAREDINDEXES_EVENT_STAGE_TYPE_ID": 'AB',
    "SHAREDINDEXES_GAME_TIME": 'BX',
    "SHAREDINDEXES_HAS_LINEUPS": 'AX',
    "SHAREDINDEXES_HAS_LIVE_CENTRE": 'AW',
    "SHAREDINDEXES_HOME_CURRENT_RESULT": 'AG',
    "SHAREDINDEXES_HOME_RESULT_PERIOD_1": 'BA',
    "SHAREDINDEXES_HOME_RESULT_PERIOD_2": 'BC',
    "SHAREDINDEXES_MATCH_START_UTIME": 'AD',
    "SHAREDINDEXES_PERIOD_START_UTIME": 'AO',
    "SHAREDINDEXES_SPORT_ID": 'SA',
    "SHAREDINDEXES_TOURNAMENT_NAME": 'ZA',
    "LEAGUEINDEXES_COUNTRY_ID": "ZB",
    "FULLFEEDINDEXES_TOURNAMENT_TEMPLATE_ID": "ZEE",
    "LEAGUEINDEXES_COUNTRY_NAME": "ZY",
    "SHAREDINDEXES_TOURNAMENT_STAGE_ID": "ZC",
    "LEAGUEINDEXES_TOURNAMENT_TYPE": "ZD",
    "LEAGUEINDEXES_TOURNAMENT_ID": "ZE",
    "LEAGUEINDEXES_SOURCE_TYPE": "ZF",
    "UPDATEINDEXES_HAS_LIVE_TABLE": "ZO",
    "LEAGUEINDEXES_STATS_TYPE": "ZG",
    "LEAGUEINDEXES_TOURNAMENT_TEMPLATE_KEY": "ZH",
    "LEAGUEINDEXES_TOURNAMENT_STAGE_TYPE": "ZJ",
    "LEAGUEINDEXES_TOURNAMENT_TEMPLATE_URL": "ZL",
    "LEAGUEINDEXES_SORT_KEY": "ZX",
    "LEAGUEINDEXES_STAGES_COUNT":"ZCC",
    "FULLFEEDINDEXES_CATEGORY_CAPTION": "ZAF",
    "SHAREDINDEXES_HOME_RED_CARD_COUNT": "AJ",
    "SHAREDINDEXES_AWAY_RED_CARD_COUNT": "AK"
}

r = requests.get("https://www.scoreboard.com/en/soccer/england/premier-league/results/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

script = [t["src"] for t in soup.findAll("script") if t.get("src") and "core_" in t["src"]][0]

data = soup.find("div", {"id": "tournament-page-data-results"}).text
rows = [t.split(DELIMITER_CELL) for t in data.split(DELIMITER_ROW)]

data = []
for r in rows:
    rowData = dict([(t[0], t[1]) 
        for t in (
            t.split(DELIMITER_VALUE) 
            for t in r
        )
        if len(t) > 1
    ])
    for key in indexes.keys():
        if indexes[key] in rowData:
            rowData[key] = rowData[indexes[key]]
            del rowData[indexes[key]]
    if "SHAREDINDEXES_PERIOD_START_UTIME" in rowData:
        data.append(rowData)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

r = requests.get(f"https://www.scoreboard.com{script}")
dataReg = re.search("feed_sign\s*=\s*'(.*)'", r.text, re.MULTILINE)
token = dataReg.group(1)

#get statistics for the first match df[0,0]
eventId = df["SHAREDINDEXES_EVENT_ID"].values[0]
r = requests.get(f"https://d.scoreboard.com/en/x/feed/d_su_{eventId}_en_1",
    headers = {
        "x-fsign": token
    })
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
#get the stats you want from soup
print(soup)
```

[Try this on repl.it](https://repl.it/@bertrandmartel/ScrapeSportsData)

Comment: Wow!!! This is amazing. But, I hear what you're saying about the difficulty and I have found a group of enthusiasts who are going to offer similar statistics for free. So I am working with that now. But, wow!!! Honestly, thank you! I am going to investigate your method further because it is certainly something I should try to learn!